# Codeigniter form validation allow numeric type to include comma

Tags: codeigniter, validation

When validating prices with CI I use the following rule;

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price','lang:price','required|numeric|greater_than[0.99]');
```

Is there any way to allow commas in this rule line? Or do i have to create a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From using the form validation library, I've never seen anything that would allow you to do that without a callback.

This would be the callback though:

```
function numeric_wcomma ($str)
{
    return preg_match('/^[0-9,]+$/', $str);
}
```

with a rule of

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('input', 'Input', 'callback_numeric_wcomma');
```

Comment: Thanks, was hoping there was a way of doing it in the single line but will settle for a callback

Answer (score 4):

Codeigniter 3 offers a regex validation. [Form Validation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference)

Using the regex given by Ben... No callback is required.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price','lang:price','required|numeric|greater_than[0.99]|regex_match[/^[0-9,]+$/]');
```

Comment: I believe this should be the correct answer as it's the single-liner the OP was trying to achieve.

Comment: doesnt work for me, when I type "7,5" message is saying "onlu numbers are allowed"

Comment: @Tikky my hunch is that the 7,5 is regional. I have not tested it using other regions.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price','lang:price','regex_match[/^(?!0*[.,]?0+$)\d*[.,]?\d+$/m]');
```

or do it in your codeigniter view. Add script:

```
<script>
function replace(element) {
  // set temp value
  var tmp = element.value;
  // replace everything that's not a number or comma or decimal
  tmp = tmp.replace(/[^0-9,.,-]/g, "");
  // replace commas with decimal
  tmp = tmp.replace(/,/, ".");
  // set element value to new value
  element.value = tmp;
}
</script>
```

and then use input like this:

```
<input id="something" onkeyup="replace(this)" type="text">
```